# Why is the tilt of Earth in sync with an orbit around the Sun?

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws, earth, solar-system, gyroscopes

Is there any physical reason the changing tilt of Earth (which gives rise to our seasons: Spring, Summer, Autumn and Winter) is in sync with an orbit of the Sun (i.e. one year)?

It can't just be coincidence but I cannot think of any physical reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Earth's tilt doesn't change so much as it's position around the sun changes.   Notice the North Pole sees more sun in summer than in winter cause it's tilted towards the sun in summer but not in winter.   The north pole always points in the same direction into space pretty much.

It wobbles slightly, and quite slowly, completing a full wobble every 41,000 years.  [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles#Axial_tilt_.28obliquity.29)

[image]

Comment: Oh wow I did not know it was just the position along with permanent tilt - I had always had in mind the Earth wobbled going full wobble once a year!

Comment: That's an odd drawing: it's wrong.  The northern hemisphere's Summer occurs when the Earth is at apogee, and is quite a bit farther from the sun than when at perigee (SOuthern hemisphere summer).  -- the tilt is correctly shown.

Comment: I don't think the drawing is wrong, it's just not addressing that particular point.   The scale is also way off.   :-)  I should have given the source but I've misplaced it.